# c# DataSet with 2 tables, how to delete a row from one it will delete a row from the other?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datatable, dataset

I use Visual Studio 2010

I have a DataSet with 2 tables

one (MainList) has type, name, path, parameter
the other (UpadteList) has path, hash, date

I added files to this list and it work with out problem, now I have the following

when I add file type "update"
it will be "Update","My Program", "PATH-TO-/my.setup.exe","/minimized"

if it was type "Update"
the following data goes to (UpdateList)
"PATH-TO-/my.setup.exe","asdfwefwfgg3r34t34t34t","2010-09-01"

I want when a row in the (MainList) deleted and a row with the same path in (UpdateList) exsist it will deleted too

should I use loop or (I saw) in dataSet properties use Relations

what is the best approach ?

with loops I got into some ugly bugs that delete everything in the Mainlist!

note: I use XML to store data (the data is not big)

Comment: Since you're using DataSet, I assume you're accessing a database, so why not define a foreign key constraint and leverage ON DELETE CASCADE to automatically delete the matching entry in the other table(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you have two choices

1. Use DataTable constraints such as [ForeignKeyConstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx) with DeleteRule=Cascade settings.
2. Use [RowDeleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowdeleted.aspx)/RowDeleting event on MainList data-table to look up and delete the corresponding row in other table.

Comment: @miguelmpn, cardinality of relation doesn't matter... in one to many relation, all related child rows will be deleted in #1.For #2, you have to do that manually.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now I understand Cascade it's always top to bottom. I was trying to delete the last child on a one to many relation and automatically delete the parent (which would be orphan), but it does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code is arguably the wrong place to deal with data consistency.  I'd do it in the database, either in a stored procedure or, if you're using SQL Server, possibly with [cascading deletes](http://rudesyle.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/cascading-deletes-in-sql-server/).

Comment: I use XML to store data (the data is not big)